# How to solve $dy/dt + t^2 y = 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From: Exercise 1.2.5 in Braun's *Differential Equation and their Applications*.

How do we solve $$\frac{dy}{dt} + t^2 y = 1?$$

I cannot evaluate integral
$$
\int e^{\frac{1}{3}t^3} dt.
$$

So I typed this in [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20e%5E%7B%281/3%29%20t%5E3%7D%20dt) but then... it gets some gamma function..

Comment: Are you, by any chance, at a point in the text where they talk about solution by power series?  It is very quick to come up with the Taylor series for that integral; a closed form is much more complicated.

Comment: Ah.. did you read this textbook? Then which section is the one talking about Taylor stuff? And yes... an evaluattion of it requires Gamma function and then that means no closed form?

Comment: I haven't read that textbook, no; but they can really only intend two things:  1) Write an explicit integral for $y(t)$ (as in the answer by @sds) or 2) write $y(t)$ as a power series in $t$.

Answer (score 3):

You can express this integral as a power series:  we have
$$
e^{t^3/3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\Bigl(\frac{t^3}{3}\Bigr)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{3n}}{3^n\,n!},\qquad \text{for any }t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Then
$$
\int e^{t^3/3}\,dt=C+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)3^n\,n!},
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant of integration.

Comment: Thank you for writing it up!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there isn't a closed-form solution.  You seem to have the correct integrating term, and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%2bt%5E2y%20=%201) seems to be the solution after all.  Could it be you copied the question incorrectly?  Certainly, if you had $y' + t^2y=0$, you would have a closed form solution after all.

Comment: The copy is correct, I'm sure. I think you are quite right on that we don't have to actually evaluate the integral I guess. But for a further study sake, I just posted the question...

Comment: Fair enough.  Did you want to work with the power series, as nrpeterson suggests or did you want to use the incomplete gamma function à la Wolfram?

Comment: Both of them I want if someone is glad to write those up here but I feel like it is too much to ask (maybe I guess). I think the Taylor expansion one, I can do it myself using the definition of exp. But the Gamma function one, indeed no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Solving a differential equation usually means reducing it to integrals.

Thus, writing the solution as
$$
y=e^{-\frac{t^3}{3}} (\int e^{\frac{t^3}{3}} + C)
$$
is usually good enough.

Comment: yep I got the same answer thanks.